# Prove That $3^n + 8^n$ is Not Divisible by $5$ (Using Induction)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, induction, divisibility

Prove that $3^n+8^n$ is not divisible by 5.

I know that this can be proved by using congruence and I am providing the proof by congruence below. But is there any way to **Prove** **It** **By** **Induction**.

The proof by congruence goes like this:

$3\equiv 3\pmod 5 \\ 3^2 \equiv 4\pmod 5 \\ 3^3\equiv 7\pmod 5 \\ 3^4\equiv 1\pmod 5 \\ 3^5\equiv 3\pmod 5$

Also,

$8\equiv 3\pmod 5 \\ 8^2 \equiv 4\pmod 5 \\ 8^3\equiv 7\pmod 5 \\ 8^4\equiv 1\pmod 5 \\ 8^5\equiv 3\pmod 5$

Adding the congruence up (since the same cycle repeats after the 4th power) none of them are divisible by 5 or equal to 0.

But I need a proof by **Induction**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1423667/prove-by-induction-8n-3n-is-divisible-by-5-for-all-n-geq-1) and add $2\cdot 3^n$, which is not divisible by $5$. Hence $3^n+8^n$ is not divisible by $5$.

Comment: Does it have to be by induction? It seems to be much faster just to observe that $$3^n+8^n \equiv 3^n+3^n = 2\cdot 3^n \pmod 5$$ which certainly can never have any factor of $5$. If you want to shoehorn in an induction step, prove by induction that $3^n\equiv 8^n\pmod 5$.

Comment: It would help if you explained **why** you need a proof by induction, otherwise your potential answerers who are perfectly happy with the congruence proof have little motivation to help you.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Today [all these questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3300424/discrete-math-induction-divide-by-4#comment6789886_3300424) are with induction, whether reasonably or not.

Comment: This is not by induction, but if you multiply through by $2^n$ (not divisible by $5$) you obtain (modulo $5$) $6^n+16^n\equiv 1^n+1^n= 2$ - just for the record, and to illustrate another approach.

Comment: $$\large \begin{align}{\bf Hint}\ \ &f(n\!+\!1) \ =\ 3\,f(n) + 5\cdot 8^n\\[.4em] \Rightarrow\ \  5\,\mid &\,f(n\!+\!1)\!\iff\! 5\mid f(n)\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: The proof you gave !!***IS***!! a proof by induction!

Comment: A proof that *isn't* by induction would be that $8\equiv 3 \pmod 5$ so $3^n + 8^n\equiv 2*3^n\pmod 5$ and $5,2,3$ being prime $5\not\mid 2*3^n$.  But the proof you did that $3^{n+4k} + 8^{n+4k}\equiv 3^{n} + 8^n$ and that is not divisible by $5$ if $n = 1,2,3,4,5$ *IS* a proof by induction.

Comment: Please don't be misled by the false claims that the congruence argument you gave already *is* a proof by induction. That is not true. What is true is that it is possible to use that idea to give a rigorous inductive proof, e.g. by inductively proving $\,3^{\large n} = 3^{\large 4k +r}\equiv 3^{\large r}\,$ using $\,3^{\large 4}\equiv 1,\,$ and similarly for $\,8^{\large n}.\ \  $

Comment: If one is going to insist this is not a proof by induction, then I think one should say the reason is because it is not a *proof* at all. But it is an *argument* by induction.  It is *not* the case that this is a non-inductive proof.  It very much *is* an *argument* by induction.  The question is whether this *argument* by induction is a proof or not.  Bill Dubuque seems pretty insistent it is not. I don't really care but do agree it can use some tightening up.  Particularly "the cycle repeats" should be stated more explicitly as to how that implies it's true for all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=====Answer 3:======

It's important that one realizes that whenever they use an argument that a pattern repeats or an observation will recur indefinitely, they are fundamentally relying upon and using the Principal of induction.  To wit:

They are showing something is true for a few base cases;  They are (hopefully-- sometimes this step is weak---) that if it is true for some cases is will follow  through for the next cases; and they make it clear that this will repeat and be true for an infinite or indefinite number of iterations.

So your argument *is* an argument of induction.

You've shown for base cases:  $n = 1,2,3,4,5$ That $3^n + 8^n $ are none divisible by $4$.

You state that the cycle repeats.  (You actually need to give a reason why the cycle repeats.  That is why if $3^n + 8^n\equiv K \pmod 5$ why $3^{n+4} + 8^{n+4} $ is also $\equiv K  \pmod 5$.  You just noticed that $3^{5} \equiv 3^{1}$ and $8^{5} \equiv 8^{1}$ and assumed that means it is true for all $n$ and $n + 4$.  You have to justify this.)

And therefore you concluded it is true for all $n$.

It is a principal if induction that allows you to conclude this.

So if you can give a reason why $3^{n+4}\equiv 3^{n}$ and $8^{n+4}\equiv 8^n$ you would be done.

(Hint:  $3^{n+4} = 3^{n-1}3^5\equiv 3^{n-1}3^1 \equiv 3^n\pmod 5$.  That *is*, after all, the reason you assumed the cycle repeated, isn't it?)

===== Answer 2: =======

You *DID* a proof by induction!

Notice the *key* phrase in you proof and the phrase that assures that you are done is:

> since the same cycle repeats after the 4th power

This means that if it is true for $3^n + 8^n$ it will be true for $3^{n+4} + 8^{n+4}$ and so by induction:

As you showed a Base case that it is true for $n = 1,2,3, 4$ (as well as $n=5$ and an induction case that if it is true for $n$, we can conclude it it true for all $n = 1+4k, 2+4k, 3+4k, 4+4k$.  WHich means it is true for all $n$.

That *IS* a prove by induction.

....

But another proof by induction follows.

===== Answer 1: ======

Well,  follow the rules of a proof by induction.

Base case:  $n=1$

$3^1 + 8^1 =11 $ which is not divisible by $5$.

Base case done:

Inductive case:

Assume that $3^n + 8^n$ is not divisible $5$.

Now we need to prove that thereform $3^{n+1} + 8^{n+1}$ is not divisible by $5$.

Now my advice is that when you need to prove something about $P(n+1)$ is to put it into terms of $P(n)$ and *use* what you know about $P(n)$.

$3^{n+1} + 8^{n+1} = 3*3^n + 8*8^n = 3*3^n + 3*8^n + 5*8^n= 3*(3^n + 8^n) + 5*8^n$ and....

$5$ is prime.  $5\not \mid 3$ and $5\not \mid (3^n + 8^n)$ and $5|5*8^n$ so $5 \not \mid 3*(3^n+8^n) + 5*8^n$.

Induction step done.

Principal of induction declares we are done. Base case: $3^n + 8^n$ is not divisible by $5$ for $n = 1$.  Induction case:  If $3^n+8^n$ is not divisible by $5$ for a value of $n$ then in will not be divisible by $5$ for the next value of $n$.  Therefore:  As we can get to all values of $n$ by starting at $1$ and then going the next, and the next after that, and so on.... it must be true that $3^n +8^n$ is not divisible by $5$ for any natural $n$.

By the way...

Comment: Au contraire: there is no "proof by induction" in the OP. OP has an *idea* for an inductive proof, but does *not* have a rigorous proof. It is *absolutely essential* to distinguish between the two. Handwaving is not proof.

Comment: Hmmmm.... point taken.  But if one thinks it is "absolutely essential" that his proof by formal, then I think our efforts need to be to point out that his proof (which the OP does think is complete) is not; and although the OP thinks his idea is *not* induction, that we should point out that it most certainly *is*, and our advice should not be to find a *different* proof but to help him formally complete the induction idea he began.

Comment: The OP's claim that "the cycle repeats" is an *idea* for an inductive proof. The point of teaching induction is to show how to make *rigorous* such pre-inductive *intuition*. It is pedagogically damaging to claim that such handwaving suffices for *proof*. As such it would be much better to  rephrase your claim  "That IS a prove(sic) by induction"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have understood the parts I have left out in my proof.

Comment: Maybe... but that misses the point.  The OP should learn to recognize inductive thinking and "the cycle repeats" *is* inductive thinking.  I think I am going to disagree with you about what is and is not pedagogically damaging.  I think expecting proofs to have magic formulas that if you say the right magic words they work, is pedagogically damaging.  And again, if this is *not* an acceptable proof it is because it needs, formalizing; *NOT* because it isn't induction.

Comment: Ok, then I'm afraid I will have to downvote. "The cycle repeats" is a claim that needs to be both *precisely* formulated then *rigorously* proved by induction. Your claim that such vague handwaving suffices as proof is very misleading and damaging to those who wish to learn induction. OP did NOT do a proof by induction.

Comment: I never said such "handwaving" suffices as a formal proof.  I said such handwaving was an induction argument.  I don't care and I don't think any question was asked about formality or rigor.  But a question was asked about induction.  I think it is vital that a student is taught that any "the cycle repeats" and "and so on statement" rely upon and imply induction and induction is *essential* to such arguments. To *NOT* do so is to be misleading and damaging.   Any criticism about handwaving or rigor is just arguing over price.

Comment: But we don't seem to disagree about inductive *intuition*. Rather, we disagree about what constitutes an inductive *proof* (you twice wrongly claimed that the OP did a *proof* by induction). If you replaced "proof" by "idea" or "intuition" then  I would not object. In my experience teaching induction I have seen many students struggle greatly while attempting to convert their intuition about similar "cycling" into a rigorous inductive proof. You may be misjudging this difficulty given that you already know well such techniques.

Comment: In particular it will not be clear to many readers *precisely* which "principal(sic) of  induction" you *implicitly* invoke in "Answer 3" (it is not even clear to me, since I  can see *various* ways).  It is essential to be *precise*, otherwise anyone can claim that some handwaving about "cycling" is a "proof by induction". But it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it by induction as well. Note that:

$3^{n+1}+8^{n+1}=3^n\times 3+8^n\times (3+5)=(3^n+8^n)\times 3+5\times 8^n$

By induction hypothesis the first term is not divisible by $5$ while the second term is obviously divisible by $5$. The required result follows.

Comment: "you can do it by induction **as well**".  BUt what the OP had done, *was* induction.  This is doing it by induction differently.

Answer (score 2):

You can go like this. For the base case, let $n=1$. Then
$$3^n+8^n = 3+8 = 11,$$
which is not divisible by $5$.

For the induction step, let $n\geq 1$ be arbitrary and assume that $3^n+8^n$ is not divisible by $5$. Now

\begin{align*}
3^{n+1} + 8^{n+1} &= 3\cdot 3^n + 8\cdot 8^n\\
&= 3\cdot 3^n + (3+5)\cdot 8^n\\
&= 3\cdot 3^n + 3\cdot 8^n + 5\cdot 8^n\\
&= 3(3^n + 8^n) + 5\cdot 8^n.
\end{align*}
The first term is not divisible by $5$ by the induction hypothesis, and because $3$ and $5$ are relatively prime, so since $5$ divides the second term, it does not divide their sum.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be a bit different:

note that $3^{n+1}+8^{n+1}=8(3^{n}+8^n)-5(3^n)$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

$$3^n + 8^n \equiv 3^n + 3^n \equiv 2*3^n \not\equiv 0 \bmod 5$$

because $2*3^n$ does not contain a factor $5$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that

$$3^{n+1}+8^{n+1}=3(3^n+8^n)+(8-3)8^n=3P+5Q$$

with P not a multiple of 5, according to the recurrence, and Q integer, will do.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- Another way very easy: Take modulo $10$

If $n=4k,\space 4k+1,\space 4k+2,\space 4k+3$ we have respectively

$3^n+8^n\equiv7,\space 1,\space 3,\space 9\pmod{10}$ It is never congruent to $5$ because all multiple of $5$ ends in $5$ or $0$.